# Running static bins in a chroot

Tags: linux, npm, chroot, alpine-linux

I'm running into an issue where static bins that I've copied over to my chroot directory do not run but return with an error message `/bin/sh: npm: not found` I also earlier ran into the same issue with pip.

I'm copying them over by running `cat /usr/bin/npm > /ns/001/usr/bin/npm` , running `chroot ns/001` and then `npm` gives me the not found error, surpisingly every single dynamically linked bin that I've copied over using mkchroot works perfectly and as expected.

What I'm I missing to get static bins I've copied over to my chroot to work?

Comment: Are you sure that it’s a static binary? What does `ldd /usr/bin/npm` tell?

Comment: `ldd` returns not a valid dynamic program